# What's the most streamlined way of performing a XSLT transformation in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

In other words, is there a faster, more concise way of writing the following code:

```
//Create an object for performing XSTL transformations
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/xslt/" + xsltfile.Value), new XsltSettings(true, false), new XmlUrlResolver());

//Create a XmlReader object to read the XML we want to format
//XmlReader needs an input stream (StringReader)
StringReader sr = new StringReader(node.OuterXml);
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr);

//Create a StringWriter object to capture the output from the XslCompiledTransform object
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

//Perform the transformation
xslt.Transform(xr, null, sw);

//Retrieve the transformed XML from the StringWriter object
string transformedXml = sw.ToString();
```

UPDATE (thanks for all the answers so far!):

Sorry for my vagueness: by "faster" and more "concise" I mean, **am I including any unnecessary steps?** Also, **I would love a more "readable" solution** if someone has one. I use this code in a small part of a web application I'm developing, and I'm about to move it to a large part of the application, so I want to make sure it's as neat as can be before I make the move.

Also, I get the XML from a static class (in a separate data access class library) which communicates with a database. I also manipulate the transformed XML string before shipping it off to a web page. I'm not sure if the input/response streams are still viable in this case.

One more thing: the XML and the XSLT supplied may change (users of the application can make changes to both), so I think I would be forced to compile each time.

Comment: I'd say that there are probably more readable ways of writing the above code, but you have the essential steps in there.  I'm not sure what you mean by "faster" though?

Comment: If you're transforming the xml to be displayed client-side, is there are a reason you're not using the asp:XML control?  It's way simpler to display the transformed string, but I don't know how you're using it browser-side.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63cbk9e7(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Jim The asp:XML control is deprecated as it uses the old, slow XslTransform Class - see http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000513.html  Shame, as it was useful.

Comment: @Jim and Dan: I'm using a custom control on the client-side that essentially does the same thing as this asp:XML control with a little bit extra functionality. I would love to wrap/extend that control. Is there an alternative?

Comment: A minor issue, but I would encapsulate StringReader, XmlReader and StringWriter in using statements.

Comment: Why do you need the XML as a string? You only use the XML APIs with XML. If you don't play with strings, your code is a lot better.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for pointing that out.  I forgot that I had come across the deprecation last time I went to use the control and had to use the code I posted in my answer below.  Unfortunately, i4i, Inc of Toronto just won a case which bans MS Word from being sold for transforming (hiding implementation of?) XML-based content.  If their patent (1998 date) holds up, I wonder how soon it will be before XML transformation is removed from .NET framework?  MS will appeal and probably offer $$ to the company, but it's a matter of principal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's code I did for my ASP.NET, which is very similar to yours:

```
  XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("output.xml");

        XDocument transformedDoc = new XDocument();
        using (XmlWriter writer = transformedDoc.CreateWriter())
        {
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            transform.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader("books.xslt")));
            transform.Transform(xDoc.CreateReader(), writer);
        }

        // now just output transformedDoc
```

Comment: You are not disposing of the XmlReader and StreamReader.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a large XSLT you can save the overhead of compiling it at runtime by compiling the XSLT into a .NET assembly when you build your project (e.g. as a post-build step). The compiler to do this is called [**`xsltc.exe`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399405.aspx) and is part of Visual Studio 2008.

In order to load such a **pre-compiled XSLT** you will need .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 or later installed on your server (the feature was introduced with SP1).

For an example check Anton Lapounov's blog article:

> [**XSLTC — Compile XSLT to .NET Assembly**](http://blogs.msdn.com/antosha/archive/2007/05/28/xsltc-compile-xslt-to-.net-assembly.aspx)

If pre-compiling the XSLT is not an option you should consider **caching** the `XslCompiledTransform` after it is loaded so that you don't have to compile it everytime you want to execute the transform.

Answer (score 3):

Don't have time to do a full example, but some notes:

1. XML is not the same as System.String. Get it from the class library as XDocument or XmlDocument; finish with it as XDocument or XmlDocument.
2. You can use the ASP.NET `Cache` to store the compiled XSL, with a cache dependency on when the .XSLT file changes.
3. Don't convert the XML to a string then back to XML. Use `node.CreateNavigator().ReadSubTree()`.
4. Similarly, use `XPathNavigator.AppendChild` to get an `XmlWriter` that will write into an XML Document.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but sorry, I'm a little confused. I'm converting from XML to a string and then putting that directly onto a page. I'm not converting back into XML nor am I altering any XML. You mentioned that I should avoid strings altogether; if I need to plant transformed XML directly onto a web page is there a way to do that without converting to a string?

Comment: How are you "planting" the XML into the web page? Instead, use `XmlDocument.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)` or the equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention ASP.NET, the question is whether you can use the response stream directly for your transform output and whether you can use the input stream directly if it is a POST...

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite the code like this:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/xslt/" + xsltfile.Value);
XmlReader reader = CreateXmlReader(node.OuterXml);
string transformedXml = Transform(path, reader);

private XmlReader CreateXmlReader(string text)
{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);
    return XmlReader.Create(reader);
}

private string Transform(string xsltPath, XmlReader source)
{
    XsltCompiledTransform transformer = new XsltCompiledTransform();
    transformer.Load(
        xsltPath, 
        new XsltSettings(true, false), 
        new XmlUrlResolver());

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.Transform(source, null, writer);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

The reason why I'd rewrite the code like this is because each block of code now has one and only one purpose.  This makes it easier to read and understand.  Additionally, the code requires less comments because a lot of information can be inferred from the names of the function and its parameters.

Comment: @John What in my code needs deterministic disposal?  If I were working with disk files, then I could understand placing a using statement around the creation of the XmlReader ... but in this case we're not so I felt that letting the garbage collector handle it would be fine.

Comment: +1 for readability; thanks for your help. I have a separate "XMLHelper" class with some common utilities I'm using throughout the web application; these methods might integrate quite nicely in there.

Comment: Anything you create that implements `IDisposable` needs to be disposed.

Comment: That's not quite true. Anything that implements disposable will be disposed when garbage collected. IDisposable just lets you explicitly release unmanaged resources. It's generally a good idea to call it explicitly when you know you're done, but it doesn't *need* to be disposed manually.